# how to responsive and fix a checkbox in css

Tags: html, css

i want fix and match blue color checkbox in table

like this image
This image is for when the browser is in full screen
http://s8.picofile.com/file/8368937534/%D8%B3%D8%B3.jpg

But for me when I shrink the browser it looks like the photo below
http://s9.picofile.com/file/8368937576/%D8%B4%D8%B4.jpg

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  /* padding-left: 35px; */
  /* margin-bottom: 12px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 107px;
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<th scope="row">7:00</th>
<td>
  <label class="container" style="direction:rtl">
    <input type="checkbox"checked="checked"/>
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</td>
```

thanks.

Comment: .checkmark {width: 100%;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 checkmark {width: 100%;}
```

and

```
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid #2196f3;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```